# How to check if a series of files exist through bash sequence expansion?

Tags: bash

I have a series of files named:

```
File.1.txt
File.2.txt
File.3.txt
File.4.txt
File.5.txt
File.6.txt
...
```

I would like to see if a series of them exist, then executing something, by doing,

```
START=20
END=30
if ls File.{${START}..${END}}.txt >/dev/null 2>&1;
then
    echo "Some action"
else
    echo "Do this"
fi
```

However, it seems the middle part is not expanding as I would like. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: `man bash` says: `Brace expansion is performed before any other expansions`

Comment: `if eval ls File.{${START}..${END}}.txt ; then`... may work, but `eval` is often a security risk, don't get in the habit of using it to solve problems. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thanks, can you elaborate on the security risk?

Comment: `eval` allows for injection attacks. There is quite a bit about this available on the internet. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls -l `seq -f "File.%0.0f.jpg" -s\\  20 30`
```

Experiment with

`seq -f "File.%0.0f.jpg`